# Cannot see files from Finder but I can from Terminal

Tags: finder, permission, macos

I have one folder where ExifRenamer (some tool for renaming images by date created) put my renamed pictures, but I cannot see them from Finder. I can see the files with ***ls -la*** but I cannot see it from Finder. How can I change make it "normal" 
CMD SHIFT dot (.) won't show files.

```
-rw-------  1 nemb  staff    6033609 May  1 18:19 2019-05-01_18-19-42.jpg
-rw-------@ 1 nemb  staff    4645069 May  4 21:02 2019-05-01_18-30-14.jpg
```

Comment: What is the full path to these files?

Comment: Are you sure you look into the correct folder in Finder? Ie: In that path where you used `ls -la`, does `open .` then also give you invisibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo mv -r /path/to/.folder /path/to/newfolder`
For example, if the folder was named `.images`, was located on your desktop, and you wanted to see it as `images2` you would type `sudo mv -r Desktop/.images Desktop/images2`.

You could also try running `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` and then relaunch Finder, which would instead show all files and folders, including hidden ones (anything starting with a .).

Comment: The OP mentioned that **⇧⌘.** didn't work; however, `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` doesn't immediately show hidden files! One must also restart Finder, e.g.: `killall Finder`

Comment: Thank you @user3439894, I forgot to mention that. I've now added it

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` output of the second file contains the `@` symbol, indicating extended attributes. You can [view extended attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19/29720) with the

```
xattr -l filename
```

command. You can use the chflags command to un-hide the file

```
chflags nohidden filename
```

or remove all extended attribtues with

```
xattr -d filename
```